# Call a function starting only with the function name as a string (ES6 syntax)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, constants

I'm doing a weird thing where I get the name of a function, and call the function with that name, like this:

```
function myFunc(){
    //do somethng
};
var myFuncName = 'myFunc';
window[myFuncName](); // Expected result.
```

...which works, but now I've defined the func using ES6 `const` naming, `window[myFuncName]` is undefined:

```
const myFunc = () => {
    //do somethng
};
var myFuncName = 'myFunc';
window[myFuncName](); // window[myFuncName] is not a function.
```

Does anyone know how to call an ES6 function when you have only it's name as a string? I'm working in a browser Web Extension but think this is a general JavaScript problem. Thanks!

Comment: Without using `eval` there's no way to do dynamic identifier resolution in the local scope. The best alternative I would recommend, is to make your "own scope" just a regular object literal and assign your functions as properties there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd only be possible with `eval`, which shouldn't be used:

```
eval(myFuncName + '()');
```

Instead, change your code so that the function is put onto an *object* (even if it's not the window), then use ordinary bracket notation to look up the property value (just like you're doing with `window`, except with `fns` instead), and call the retrieved function:

```js
const fns = {
  myFunc() {
    console.log('do something');
  }
};
const myFuncName = 'myFunc';
fns[myFuncName]();
```

If you want to more closely imitate `const` for the property on the object, use `Object.defineProperty` to make sure the function property can't be deleted nor reassigned, via `configurable: false`:

```js
'use strict';
const fns = {};
Object.defineProperty(fns, 'myFunc', {
  configurable: false,
  value: () => {
    console.log('do something');
  }
});
const myFuncName = 'myFunc';
fns[myFuncName]();

// can't reassign property:
fns.myFunc = 'foo';
```

Comment: `eval(myFuncName)()` would be the same for `eval` which shouldn't be used.

Comment: Sure, you can put the `()`s outside the `eval` if you want, but it doesn't make any difference

Comment: @CertainPerformance Great, thanks. I've gone with aliasing `myFunc` in a `fns` obj, like: ```const fns = {
  myFunc: myFunc
};
fns[myFuncName]();```
Glad to have avoided `eval`!